# Kile freezes running pdflatex

Tags: compiling, kile

When I run kile I get the message:

> QStatusBar::insertWidget: Index out of range (4), appending widget

and I am not able to compile from Kile. While I press `pdfLatex` inside Kile, it freezes. What can I do to debug/fix this? I am using SuSE Linux 11.4

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I don't know if SuSE has a bug tracking system, but if so, report a bug, check for updates, and you could also ask on a more SUSE (or possibly KDE) specific forum.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Kile and you should probably report it as a bug over [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) (assuming it isn't already fixed).

The bug stems from addressing a non-existing widget in an array.